# Equalize local variable to literal in SOQL

Tags: soql

Is there a way to equalize local variable to literal in SOQL?
Something like :

```
Boolean selectAll = true;
Id someId = '0011A00001TqAPE'
[SELECT NAME FROM ACCOUNT WHERE (Id=:someId OR :selectAll=True)];
```

This query produces a compilation error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this.
However as the specs says 'fieldName comparisonOperator value' you will need a valid 'fieldName' rather than a variable on the left side of the 'comparsionOperator'.
This field may of course be a boolean but that doesn't solve your issue.
I think you need to construct a dynamic SQL in Apex...